# Corona sdk and Facebook - new Feed dialog not returning PostId after sharing in Android

Tags: android, facebook, dialog, coronasdk

I'm using the Facebook v4 plugin with Corona sdk for my app. 
To implement sharing, I use the feed dialog (I prefer it over the share dialog because it allows more flexibility, so please don't tell me to switch to the share dialog).
Up until the latest version of facebook, everything worked as expected (pretty much)

- if a share was successful, I'd get a PostId in the callback (e.g. "fbconnect://success?PostID=123456789")
- if a share was unsuccessful (for example, cancelled by the user), there won't be a PostId (e.g. "fbconnect://success?PostID=" or "fbconnect://success?PostID=(null)")

However, since the **latest Facebook update for Android** I sometimes get a new feed dialog. In this new dialog, after a successful share I get the callback: "fbconnect://success?PostID=".

As I mentioned, I get this new feed dialog only sometimes, so it looks like Facebook is testing it out. 
This is definitely a bug on Facebook's end, since I must have a way to determine if the user shared or not. 
Any helpful thoughts?

Comment: In replay to a recent bug report Facebook said they are indeed redirecting some users to the Share dialog automatically, even if the Feed dialog was initially requested, for UX testing purposes. _“since I must have a way to determine if the user shared or not”_ – why “must” you? I hope you are aware that you are not allowed to “reward” users for sharing in any way, right? (If not, it’s time you go read [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).)

Comment: I must have a way to know if a user shared or not for statistics and marketing purposes, and not for rewarding users. I'm certain Facebook won't object to me testing which shares put people off and which not.

Comment: The Share dialog only returns a post id, if the app has `publish_actions` permission from the user – that is by design. And if your users partly get the Share dialog shown instead of the Feed dialog, as part of Facebook’s testing process, then there’s little you can do about it (apart from requesting that permission beforehand.)

Comment: If I can share without the permission, why do I need it to get the post id? It makes no sense...

Comment: Because the post id allows to determine the user id – and for users that did not even login to your app and grant it permission, that is of course none of your business.